# Multiple XOpenDisplay(NULL) Causes Window not to Be Mapped

Tags: c++, x11

Below is the code that will cause a XWindow not to be Mapped. I am very well aware that I can use one Display and it will work. This example is a simplified version of what is currently happening in my library. My window is created in a dynamic lib inside a class that gets its own Display structure. Then in my application's executable which links to my library I have my main loop which processes events and also needs access to a Display. I could store the Display in a systems object but would prefer not doing this since Windows does not follow the same paradigm for creating its windows, and my library will be cross platform. Is there a way to have two display objects and still get my X11 window to map correctly? I have tried XFlush() but that did not seem to work. If more code is needed I can provide it.

```
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <cstring>

int main (int argc, char *argv []) {
  Display *display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  int screen = DefaultScreen(display);

  XSetWindowAttributes window_attributes;
  window_attributes.border_pixel = 5;
  window_attributes.border_pixel = BlackPixel(display, screen);
  window_attributes.background_pixel = WhitePixel(display, screen);
  window_attributes.event_mask = ExposureMask | KeyPressMask | ButtonPress |
    StructureNotifyMask | ButtonReleaseMask | KeyReleaseMask |
    EnterWindowMask | LeaveWindowMask | PointerMotionMask | Button1MotionMask |
    VisibilityChangeMask | ColormapChangeMask;
  unsigned long valuemask = CWEventMask | CWBackPixel | CWBorderPixel;

  Window window = XCreateWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screen),
       0, 0, 800, 600, 5, DefaultDepth(display, screen),
       InputOutput, CopyFromParent, valuemask, &window_attributes);

  Display *map_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  XMapWindow(map_display, window);

  XEvent event;
  bool done = False;
  Display *loop_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
  while (!done) {
    while (XPending(loop_display) > 0) {
      XNextEvent(loop_display, &event);
      switch (event.type) {
      case Expose: {
        if (event.xexpose.count != 0) {
          break;
        }
      }
        break;
      case ClientMessage: {
        if (strcmp(XGetAtomName(loop_display, event.xclient.message_type),
          "WM_PROTOCOLS") == 0) {
          done = True;
        }
      }
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I could see this being useful, especially when creating a glx device context in a graphics library that is separate from your windowing library.

---

Running valgrind on my unit test shows:

```
==23214== 5,104 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 37 of 41
==23214==    at 0x4A082F7: realloc (in /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==23214==    by 0x3A1E609D92: xcb_connect_to_fd (in /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==23214==    by 0x3A1E60CC22: xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info (in /usr/lib64/libxcb.so.1.1.0)
==23214==    by 0x3EBB4409C9: _XConnectXCB (in /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==23214==    by 0x3EBB431F3E: XOpenDisplay (in /usr/lib64/libX11.so.6.3.0)
==23214==    by 0x4C11586: gl_wrapper::graphics::context_descriptor::context_descriptor()
(platform.h:16)
==23214==    by 0x40CE56: context_descriptor_tests::test_context_descriptor_ctor()
(context_descriptors.h:14)
==23214==    by 0x40D1BF: TestDescription_suite_context_descriptor_tests_test_context_descriptor_ctor::runTest()
(runner.cpp:34)
==23214==    by 0x403A67: CxxTest::RealTestDescription::run() (RealDescriptions.cpp:106)
==23214==    by 0x406A53: CxxTest::TestRunner::runTest(CxxTest::TestDescription&)
(TestRunner.h:87)
==23214==    by 0x406962: CxxTest::TestRunner::runSuite(CxxTest::SuiteDescription&)
(TestRunner.h:73)
==23214==    by 0x406836: CxxTest::TestRunner::runWorld() (TestRunner.h:57)
```

Comment: I'd call that a rare case where you use multiple X connections and given that Xlib is rather hackish, I'm not surprised that it doesn't work. Have you checked the bug reports for that library? Have you considered using XCB instead?

Comment: Interesting enough Fedora 19's implementation of X might be calling into xcb?

See comment appended to original post.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `XSync` with a relevant display after both `XCreateWindow` and `XMapWindow`.